# Add Slide effect to Sliderman.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Sliderman.js (http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/examples.html) but can't seem to figure out how to get a simple effect to work, all the big ones work fine, just want my images to slide in from the right and slide out from the left so basically like a loop, need to modify the code but don't know how, help!

The source code is avaliable here: http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/examples.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to paste your code so far to give us a starting point.
I think you just need to specify move and a start position in the effects. Like so:

Sliderman.slider({
    container: 'whatever',
    width: 800,
    height: 200,
    effects: { move:true, right:true, duration:400 }, 
    display: {autoplay: 3000}
  });

Code taken from example 3 on the page you linked to. It cycles through various options - I've just grabbed the right to left movement one.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it difficult to add a second div or p tag and give that tag a transition effect but have it display first and overlay it with an image?

Comment: I shouldn't think so although it is difficult to picture what you are actually working on. If you paste your code into your question or on jsfiddle.net it is easier for us to help :)

Comment: Thanks, just something i've been trying to do, is there a way to add text over the image, first the image transitions into view then the text appers over it, and after 5 seconds, both text and image fade slide away making way for the second text / image to appear? How do you do that and/or where can I find more info on achieving this?